# How to autowire or get the bean which is active in running application and is required by one of it's dependent jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp

Problem: I have a application which has simple SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory bean defined.
There is a component created which has generic implementaion for RabbitListenerAroundAdvice which is meant to be applicable to any application which has SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory bean and is added as dependency. 
One way to set the advicechain is in the application which means every application relying on this advice need to undergo a change.
I want to set the advice chain of the SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory in the RabbitListenerAroundAdvice component for which I need the SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory bean defined in the application. How do I get this bean in order to  set advicechain?

Example: Bean as in application

```
@Bean
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, @Value("${queue.consumers}") int concurrentConsumer) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(concurrentConsumer);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(concurrentConsumer);
        factory.setPrefetchCount(1);
        return factory;
    }
```

RabbitListenerAroundAdvice component as below:

```
//set the advice of the SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory so that the message is intercepted.
 public class RabbitListenerAroundAdvice implements MethodInterceptor {
@Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
        //business logic to to check before handling the message
        final Object result = methodInvocation.proceed();
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't... Please don't. You shouldn't be modifying those things on a per message basis. It is a singleton (and a factory) which is dangerous. Also as mentioned it is a factory, which creates a listener container, chancing the factory won't do anything as the listener-container has already been created.

Comment: But is a way defined in spring to hook before/After message processing using RabbitListener. I only need the singleton factory bean to set the advicechain.